# Filter a column with specific criteria from another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filtering

I am trying to filter Table1:

```
 Table1

 Region             mCode   pCode
 Europa               AD    E
 Rest of the world    AD    O
 East Europa          AE    O
 Outside              AE    L
 Rest of the world    AE    E
 Asia                 AF    O
 North America        AG    D
 Rest of the world    AG    L
 North America        AI    D
 Rest of the world    AI    L
 America              AI    L
```

There are four different values for pCode (D,L,E,O) and mCode can be repeated.

I need to get only those rows where mCode has a pCode with higest priority according to:

```
Highest priority     pCode = D
Second priority      pCode = L 
Third priority       pCode = E 
last priority        pCode = O
```

For example mCode 'AE' appears in 3 rows and pCode are 'O','L' and 'E' in different rows. According to pCode priority the result shows the row where pCode is second priority 'L' since there is no row for 'AE' with higher priority than 'L'. The rest of the rows don't really matter.

The desired result has mCode as unique values:

```
 Region            mCode    pCode
 Europa            AD       E
 Outside           AE       L
 Asia              AF       O
 North America     AG       D
 North America     AI       D
```

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense to me. Where did "Rest of the world" go? You need to explain the logic here better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I think you are trying to do, although it's not 100% clear from the question:

```
select *

from (

  select *
       , row_number() over (
           partition by [Region] 
           order by case when [pCode] = 'D' then 1
                         when [pCode] = 'L' then 2
                         when [pCode] = 'E' then 3
                         when [pCode] = 'O' then 4
                         else 5 end) as [RN]

  from Table1
  ) sub

where [RN] = 1
and [pCode] in ('D','L','O','E')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aaea2d/4/0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was close. I have updated my post. I need to get only those rows where mCode has a pCode with higest priority according to:
 
Highest priority     pCode = D
Second priority     pCode = L
Third priority         pCode = E 
last priority            pCode = O 

For example mCode 'AE' appears in 3 rows and pCode are 'O','L' and 'E' in different rows. According to pCode priority the result shows the row where pCode is second priority 'L' since there is no row for 'AE' with higher priority than 'L'. The rest of the rows don't really matter.

Comment: @SQL_NewUser I've updated the question to restrict to only lines in the priority